# PHP variable in WordPress database query

Tags: database, query

When running the following code :

```
$voucher = 'MK0186';
$is_in_database = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM my_codes_table WHERE code =" . $voucher );
```

I get : WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'MK0186' in 'where clause']. I don't understand why.

Comment: Aside from the complete lack of sanitisation, this is an SQL issue, not a WordPress issue, and is offtopic

Comment: Also wrap your values in quotes, you will want to look at the WPDB classes prepare method

Comment: I think it's a question & answer website, not a question & criticism website :) I still don't know what the solution to my particular problem is.

Comment: @TomJNowell effectively answered your question already - wrap your value in quotes. Criticism is often part of an honest answer. And yes, this is off-topic.

Comment: @drake035 your code is not perfect, perfect code does not exist, and criticism is helpful. I suggest you grow thicker skin and go to the SQL and Database exchange site where this question would be on topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WPDB prepare method is what you're after, as this will prep your data for passing to a query and also ensure data matches the type its intended to be whilst also handling quoting where necessary at the same time.

Fixing your code *could* be a matter of..

```
$voucher = 'MK0186';
$is_in_database = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM my_codes_table WHERE code = '$voucher'" );
```

.. but you'd be better advised to write it this way ..

```
$voucher = 'MK0186';

$is_in_database = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT * FROM my_codes_table 
        WHERE code = %s", 
        $voucher 
    ) 
);
```

Example query with 2 numeric values and a string value.

```
$num1 = 5;
$num2 = 10;
$string = 'Some String!!';
$query = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT * FROM sometable 
        WHERE column1 = %d 
        AND column2 = %d
        AND column3 = %s
        ", 
        $num1, $num2, $string
    ) 
);
```

In short... your string value isn't quoted, that's the issue. Use the `$wpdb->prepare` method and it'll take care of that for you.